# Font chooser in ListView (multiple fonts in a ListView)

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-fonts

I have an app where I want the user to be able to select a font. I've already downloaded fonts in the `assets` folder of the `project`.

Now I want to merge all the fonts in a `ListView`.

Then I want to set an onClickListener and want to get the selected font.

I want each line of the `ListView` to display the font name and the right font for that name.

Comment: I would recommend using a SettingsActivity to do so, I have a sample code if you are interested.

Comment: You can also use a library https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your fonts with this way

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "font.ttf");
```

So whenever user clicked on an item of `ListView` store name of the font in a shared preferences then you can get selected font with this :

```
 Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("selected_font_name"));
```

Comment: Yes, however I want the name of the fonts in a listview but also apply the right font to that name.